# How do I know the Y value when running the locate command?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I'm trying to find a woodland mansion in creative, but I need help with the Y.

When I run `/locate`, it says at block `1576 (y)? -11176`

How do I know where to go if it won't tell me the Y value?

Answer (score 5):

Locations using the `/locate` command never give y values. It doesn't matter, just run

```
/tp @s 1676 100 -11176
```

and you should be there. Whenever you use the `/locate` command, just teleport yourself to y 100 and then dig down until you find your structure if it's something like an abandoned mineshaft.