# Woodland Mansion structure Y coordinate

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

trying to find a woodland mansion in creative, but I need help with the Y.

When I run /locate, it says at block -9368 (y)? -28920

How do I know where to go if it won't tell me the Y value?

Could someone please help with these coordinates
-9368 (y?) -28920

Comment: You just asked [the same exact question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/378981/258509) yesterday, why would you ask it again?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I know the Y value when running the locate command?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/378981/how-do-i-know-the-y-value-when-running-the-locate-command)

Answer (score 0):

You don’t need the Y value as this only specifies the elevation, just run `/tp @s -9368 128 -28920`. As natural terrain generation rarely goes past y128, and will be a lot closer to sea level (y63) in a dark forest, teleporting to y128 will allow you to drop down directly on the roof of the mansion.

Comment: I’ve removed your reminder from your post because it should be a comment, not in an answer.